# Get token from API Microsoft Graph

Tags: talend

How to get the token from en API Microsoft Graph from a Talend job?
Under postman it's ok to generate the token but with a tRest component I don't know what kind of parameters I should use and where. All I get is a status200 answer that ask me to sign in.

I tried multiple kind of connection with tRest. Adding a xml body too.
If I use the token from postman with a classic API call in Talend, for exemple https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me, it works. So I need to get first the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the below workflow:
tREST -> tExtractJson -> tSetGlobalVar

[image: workflow]

As per the Microsoft documentation, tREST configuration is as per the below (with client secret):
[image]

Replace the yellow bits with your own details.

Then extract your token from the response body and save it into globalMap for future use.

If you use other methods than shared secret to identify, look at the Microsoft Graph API documentation [Get a Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) to see what information you need to send in your POST request.

Comment: The method for the /token url works perfectly, but after more dev on my job, it gives me back a partial token with "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" when I do a tRest with a /me for exemple, when using this token. (the token on postman is longer that this one)

So I guess I should do /authorize url first, then try /token?

Comment: Ok after few tests with my colleague who worked on Azure side: permission was on Delegated (for users) and not on Application. Just in case I let the information here if someone gets the same issue. NOW it's fine :)